# SQL Server - Consulta mostrar registro repetidos de una tabla

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo la tabla InfoPersonal en la cual se registra el IDpersonal varias veces.

La tabla maneja IDtabla(pk), IDpersonal, Nombre, Apellido, actividad, instituto.

Necesito extraer solo 1 registro de cada IDpersonal de la tabla InfoPersonal, sin importar cual registro duplicado se tome

Así puedo ver el total de registros sin duplicados

```
Select distinct IDpersonal from InfoPersonal
```

Necesito traer algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La forma más simple de obtener los registros sin duplicados podría ser tomando el mayor (o el menor)

```
SELECT MAX(IdPersonal) as IdPersonal, usuario, actividad, tarea, Sede
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY usuario, actividad, tarea, Sede
```